# Hibernate attach and detach entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 entity classes
For ex,

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "AAA")
public Class AAA {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "bbb_id", nullable = false)
    @Valid
    BBB bbb;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "BBB")
public Class BBB {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bbb_seq_generator") 
     @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "bbb_seq", name = "bbb_seq_generator", allocationSize = 1)
     Long id;
}
```

I have a service which gets input request body as below json

```java
"aaa" : 
{
"bbb" : { "id" : 123}
}
```

I now use

```java
aaaRepository.save(aaaObj);
```

to save both `aaa` and `bbb`

I want `bbb` to be saved only when its id value is not found in the DB (`findById(id)` gives `Optional.empty`) and retain the value if already found and just save `aaa` alone in that case.

Entity `AAA` has to be persisted and entity `BBB` also to be persisted if id is null in the request body and in case if id is already present then it has to be retained the same and `AAA` has to be persisted with whatever value comes in the request body

I tried but when i try to set `bbb` explicitly to `aaa`, I get detached entity exception. For the case when id is already present in request.
I can't be without setting the id as the service layer has to know which id it should check for in the DB.

Comment: Can you please show the code how you create the entities and where the transaction boundaries are

Comment: Hi..I have edited the code part. Can u pls have a look?

Comment: I mean the code where you create the entities and you assign B to A